# Converting a matrix/dataframe in R to JSON object with some constraints

Tags: json, r, matrix, rjson, rjsonio

REDITED:

I have to convert a matrix in R to a JSON object with some structure in it. I am using the rjson package. Through an example, let me illustrate what I want. My specific case is the output of a recommender system code in R where the X2 X3 are the 2 closest items to a particular item X1. Also, X4,X5 are the scores of similarity associated with (X1,X2) and (X1,X3) for that row.  I want all the recommended items for every item as JSON objects and every item along with its recommended JSON object- items as a bigger JSON objects.The scores should also be incorporated into the JSON structure.

Let me explain through a example.

Suppose I have a matrix

```
X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 
1 22 23  0.8 0.5
34 4 87  0.4 0.4
23 7 92  0.6 0.5
```

I want a JSON structure for every item (every X1 for every row) along with the recommended items and the similarity scores for each combination as a separate JSON entity and this being done in sequence. I don't want an entire JSON object containing these individual ones.
Assume there is one more entity called "coid" that will be given as input to the code. I assume it is XYZ and it is same for all the rows.

```
{ "_id" : { "coid" : "XYZ", "iid" : "1"}, "items" : [ { "item" : "22", "score" : 0.8},{ "item": "23", "score" : 0.5}] }
{ "_id" : { "coid" : "XYZ", "iid" : "34"},"items" : [ { "item" : "4", "score" : 0.4},{ "item": "87", "score" : 0.4}] }
{ "_id" : { "coid" : "XYZ", "iid" : "23"},"items" : [ { "item" : "7", "score" : 0.6},{ "item": "92", "score" : 0.5}] }
```

As in the above, each entity is a valid JSON structure/object but they are not put together into a separate JSON object as a whole.

I appreciate all the help done for the previous question but somehow I feel this new alteration I have here is not related to them because in the end, if you do a toJSON(some entity), then it converts the entire thing to one JSON object. I don't want that.
I want individual ones like these to be written to a file.

I am very sorry for my ignorance and inconvenience. Please help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your json is not valid. You can check the validity for example [here](http://jsonlint.com/).

That being said, to get something similar to your desired json output, you can do as f

```
library(RJSONIO)

# recreating your matrix
m <- matrix(c(1,22,23,34,4,87,23,7,92),nrow=3,byrow=T)
colnames(m)<-c('X1','X2','X3')

# convert numeric matrix to character (if necessary)
m <- matrix(as.character(m),nrow=nrow(m))

# transform your matrix before turning into json    
p <- apply(m,MARGIN=1,FUN=function(r)list(Item=unname(r[1]),Recos=unname(r[-1])))

# jsonize
toJSON(p)
```

Result:

```
[
    {
        "Item" : "1",
        "Recos" : ["22", "23"]
    },
    {
        "Item" : "34",
        "Recos" : ["4", "87"]
    },
    {
        "Item" : "23",
        "Recos" : ["7", "92"]
    }
]
```

---

**EDIT (as per your edit) :**

```
library(RJSONIO)

# recreating your matrix
m <- matrix(c(1,22,23,34,4,87,23,7,92),nrow=3,byrow=T)
colnames(m)<-c('X1','X2','X3')

# transform your matrix before turning into json    
p <- apply(m,MARGIN=1,
           FUN=function(r){
             list(itemID=unname(r[1]),
                  recommendedItems=lapply(unname(r[-1]),
                                          FUN=function(i)list(itemID=i)))
           })

# jsonize
toJSON(p)
```

Result:

```
[{
        "itemID" : 1,
        "recommendedItems" : [{
                "itemID" : 22
            }, {
                "itemID" : 23
            }
        ]
    }, {
        "itemID" : 34,
        "recommendedItems" : [{
                "itemID" : 4
            }, {
                "itemID" : 87
            }
        ]
    }, {
        "itemID" : 23,
        "recommendedItems" : [{
                "itemID" : 7
            }, {
                "itemID" : 92
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

---

**EDIT 2 :**

Instead of writing the code for you, I'd rather try to explain how an R structure is turned into a json by RJSONIO package.

As far as json conversion is concerned, I consider 3 "kind" of objects:

1. unnamed list (or vector)
2. named list (or vector)
3. vector of one element

**1)** An unnamed list (or vector) of elements (e.g. `v <- list('a','b','c')`), is translated to json as:

```
[ element_1, element_2, element_3, ... ]
```

with `element_n` being the n-th element of the list. Of course each element of the list can be, in turn, another complex object that is turned into json following the 3 rules I am describing here.

**2)** A named list (or vector) (e.g. `n <- list(A="foo",B="bar")`), is translated to json as:

```
{ "name_1": value_1, "name_2": value_2, ...  }
```

with `name_n` being the name of the n-th element of the named list, and `value_1` the value of the n-th element of the named list. Of course each value of the named list can be, in turn, another complex object that is turned into json following the 3 rules I am describing here.

**3)** As you could correctly point out, every object in R is a vector. Even `a <- 1` is a numeric vector of one element. So, following the previous 2 rules, you would expect for example `list(x=1)` to be translated as `{ "x" : [ 1 ] }`. But thanks to parameter `asIs` (FALSE by default) of `toJSON` function, vectors (**not lists**) of single elements are considered scalars.

That being said, here follows some examples:

```
toJSON(list(list(A=2),1:3))
> '[ { "A": 2 }, [ 1, 2, 3 ] ]'

toJSON(list(A=list(1),B=list(C="X"),D=1))
> '{ "A": [ 1 ], "B": { "C": "X" }, "D": 1 }'
```

Comment: The question has been edited. Please help me on how to make the new JSON structure I have asked for.

Comment: @user2878729: check my edit. BTW try to understand how json is generated starting from an R structure. It's really easy ;)

Comment: Can we generate separate JSON Objects for every row independent of one another? like for example:

Comment: I have edited my question yet again. I am very sorry about it. Please go through it and help me.

Comment: @user2878729: Stackoverflow is not a place where you can ask users to write code for you, but rather a place where you can learn how to solve your own problems. Following this idea, I have posted a description of how RJSONIO works. I'm confident you will be able to accomplish your task after reading my explanation ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the appropriately nested list

```
m <- matrix(c(1,22,23,34,4,87,23,7,92),nrow=3,byrow=T)
colnames(m)<-c('X1','X2','X3')

m1 <- apply(m,1, function(x) {
     list(itemID = unname(x[1]), 
          recommendedItems = lapply(unname(x[2:3]), function(y) {
             list(itemID = y)}
          ))
       })


 cat(toJSON(m1))
[
  {
    "itemID":      1,
    "recommendedItems": [
      {
        "itemID":     22 
      },
      {
        "itemID":     23 
      } 
    ] 
  },
{
    "itemID":     34,
    "recommendedItems": [
      {
        "itemID":      4 
      },
      {
        "itemID":     87 
      } 
    ] 
  },
{
    "itemID":     23,
    "recommendedItems": [
      {
        "itemID":      7 
      },
      {
        "itemID":     92 
      } 
    ] 
  } 
]
```

Answer (score 0):

The desired json object is not a valid. You should transform your data.frame to a list before transforming it to a  json object. For example you can do this:

```
cat(toJSON(apply(dat,1,function(x)list(item =unname(x[1]),
                                       Recos=unname(x[-1])))))

[
 {
 "item": 1,
"Recos": [ 22, 23 ] 
},
{
 "item": 34,
"Recos": [ 4, 87 ] 
},
{
 "item": 23,
"Recos": [ 7, 92 ] 
} 
]
```

Comment: The question has been edited. Please help me on how to make the new JSON structure I have asked for. Thanks.